# Share same item height with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

My pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QwMRNL

How can I make those 3 divs share the same row height AND always take up the full height of the screen?

Even where there are only 3 or 2 or 1 items. They must always share the size.

```
- 3 items means each item gets 33% height
- 2 items means each item gets 50% height
- 1 item means each item gets 100% height


<div id="flex">
  <div>Temperature</div>
  <div>Freeze</div>
  <div>Consumption</div>
</div>

#flex {
display: flex;
max-height: 100%;
align-content: center;
flex-direction: column;    
}


body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

#flex > div:nth-child(1){
background:blue;
}

#flex > div:nth-child(2){
background:red;
}

#flex > div:nth-child(3){
background:yellow;
}
```

UPDATE:

Please no change of height:100% in the body,html tags!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `justify-content:stretch;` on the container and `flex-grow:1;` on the items.

```css
.container{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content:stretch;
  width:200px;
  height:100vh;
  border:1px solid blue;
}
.item{
  flex-grow:1; 
  width:100px;
  border:1px solid red;   
}
```

```html
<h4>Red child divs will stretch to fill blue parent</h4>
<div class='container'>
  <div class='item'>One</div>
  <div class='item'>Two</div>
  <div class='item'>Three</div>
</div>
```

Comment: funny... I have the same result but different css. Why does mine work too? I do not like flexbox have multiple ways to do something... http://codepen.io/helloworld/pen/yyoWja

Comment: @Pascal, the default property of justify-context is `stretch` so you can safely omit it from my answer. Then my answer resembles your answer. BTW, my own preference is to specify default values even if they are not required--just for clarity when I review the code later. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by absolutely positioning the flex container:

```
#flex {
   display: flex;
   align-content: center;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
   flex-direction: column;
}

#flex > div:nth-child(1) {
    flex: 1;
}

#flex > div:nth-child(2) {
    flex: 1;
}

#flex > div:nth-child(3) {
     flex: 1;
}
```

[Updated codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PwKvbV)

Comment: Then what do you mean by *"always take up the full height of the screen?*"?